# jQuery HTMLElement wrapping/unwrapping

Tags: jquery, datatables

I use jQuery together with the dataTables Plugin.
dataTables provides a feature to open and close a row (means that an additional info-row can be opened under a regular row).

From http://datatables.net/api i got following well working example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable;

    // 'open' an information row when a row is clicked on
    $('#example tbody tr').click( function () {
        if ( oTable.fnIsOpen(this) ) {
            oTable.fnClose( this );
        } else {
            oTable.fnOpen( this, "Temporary row opened", "info_row" );
        }
    } );

    oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
} );
```

Now I want to add the click handler not to the whole row, but to a element in the row:

```
$("#openCompliantsTable .icon-comment").click(…
```

But of course `this` now does not refer to the `tr` element but to some child element. My attempt to change the code was to replace `this` with `$(this).parent().parent().get()`, which did not work.

Then i found out that actually `this` seems not to be the same as `$(this).get()`, even if both are `[object HTMLElement]` objects, which surprised me.

Any suggestions to get this working?

EDIT: 
My HTML table looks like this:

```
<table id="openCompliantsTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Reklamationsnummer</th>
        <th>Reklapositionsnummer</th>
        ...
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Aktion</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        ...
        <td>offen</td>
        <td><i class="icon-ok"></i><i class="icon-trash"></i><i class="icon-flag"></i><i class="icon-comment"></i></td>
      </tr>
      ...
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Are you sure `$(this).parent().parent()` finds the TR element ?

Comment: Yes, I can add some CSS classes to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) without parameters returns **an array** with all the DOM element of all the matched elements. Even if you have only one matched element, you'll get an array with one item.

With an index, .get() will retrieve **a single element**, which is you're after.

You have to use:

```
$(this).parent().parent().get(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
$(this).parent().parent().get()
```

with

```
$(this).parent().parent().get(0)
```

Your function could be:

```
$('#openCompliantsTable .icon-comment').click( function () {
    var tr = $(this).parent().parent().get(0);
    if ( oTable.fnIsOpen(tr) ) {
        oTable.fnClose(tr);
    } else {
        oTable.fnOpen(tr, "Temporary row opened", "info_row" );
    }
} );
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/kxSYE/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Or shorter:

```
$(this).parents('tr')[0];
```

This takes the first parent that is a 'tr', nesting doesn't matter and you don't have to care about how many levels you have to step up. Just be careful if you have nested tables.